# Drawing a custom shape in android

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I want to draw a custom shape like this

[image]

i tried to use it as TextView but it cause me a problem with clicking since the bottom blue part beside the arrow is considered part of the image .. so i want my shape to be only the white and orange part
How should I draw a shape like this? by code or XML Don't expect complete code, just give me idea or point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can put the white part as an image however, the entire imageview rectangle will be clickable.

Comment: You can make a custom View.

Comment: You could use a vector editor like sketch, vectors are a good way of creating custom shapes.

Comment: @Shaishav that's actually my problem i don't want the full rectangle to be clickable only the white part

Comment: @Salma yeah i figured. I guess then you have to to use `onTouchListener()` and then use some algorithm to figure out if the touch was in the clickable area or not. This will be case with custom views too since they also have rectangular containers.

Comment: To draw the white thing you could use a XferMode, but to handle clicks only in the white part - you'll need a heavy `onClickListener` to do the logic.

Comment: I didn't try but it should work. You can use orange as background and white as drawableBottom in TextView.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the click issue by cropping the original image to two shapes
then glue them together in xml and add the listener on the textviews only discarding the bottom blue part

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explore_rectangle_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/explore_rectangle"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/explore_rectangle_txt"
        android:background="@drawable/explore_arrow"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Had a similar issue, your answer helped me . Thanks